# how to select id against the selected text in drop down menu in codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have retrieved the data from category table in which i have two columns id and category and than loaded this data to page_data view where i have 2 input tittle and description one drop down menu name category the categories will be loaded from the category table now what i want is to select the id against the category and than want to insert the data in another table page_data in which i have 4 columns which are.

```
id int
cat_id int
tittle varchar(40)
description varchar(255)
```

Here is my controller where i am loading the pagedata.

```
function page_data()
    {
        $data['result']=$this->admin_model->retrieve_data();
        $this->load->view('admin/pagedata',$data);
    }
```

Here is my view of pagedata.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="insert_pagedata">
                              <fieldset>
                                <legend>Page Data</legend>
                                <div class="control-group">
                                  <label class="control-label" for="">Tittle </label>
                                  <div class="controls">
                                    <input type="text" class="span6" name="tittle">
                                  </div>
                                </div> 
                                <div class="control-group">
                                  <label class="control-label" for="select01">Select list</label>
                                  <div class="controls">
                                    <select id="select01" name="catid" class="chzn-select">
                                      <option>something</option>
                                      <?php
                                      if(isset($result))
                                      {
                                          foreach($result as $row)
                                          {
                                              $row->id;
                                              echo "<option>".$row->category."</option>";
                                          }
                                      }
                                      ?>
                                    </select>
                                  </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="control-group">
                                  <label class="control-label" for="textarea2">Textarea</label>
                                  <div class="controls">
                                    <textarea name="Description" class="input-xlarge textarea" placeholder="Enter text ..." style="width: 810px; height: 200px"></textarea>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-actions">
                                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                                  <button type="reset" class="btn">Cancel</button>
                                </div>
                              </fieldset>
                            </form>
```

I am really confuse that how can i get the id of selected category please help me out please please.

Comment: are you trying to get the `id` of the selected category in the `select` input? or are you trying to get the `value` on submit?

Comment: i am trying to get the id of against the selected category in the drop down menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its quite easy to get the id of selected text in dropdown menu change the following line like that.

```
  <?php
  if(isset($result))
  {
   foreach($result as $row)
  {
        echo "<option value='$row->id'>".$row->category."</option>";
      }
     }
    ?>
```

because you cat_id is int type and id will get selected against the category as well.

Comment: thanks a lot and yes its quite easy i was thinking for jquery and other things thanks for saving my time

Comment: think little before start programing make sketch of everything and you will be on your point. And one more thing google is your friend try to use it some times